# Play a Sound Using ObjectAL

Tags: objective-c, audio, openal, objectal

I am trying to figure out how to use objectal but I have never programmed in objective-c before (just swift and some other non-apple languages). To be frank, objectal is rather over my head, so I am wondering if there is a simple way just to play a sound using objectal that I could try to implement? It would make me happy :)

Comment: Do you mean OpenAL rather than "ObjectAL"? If you want something simpler, you could check out AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: Unfortunately I do mean ObjectAL (http://kstenerud.github.io/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/). It's apparently the best way to seamlessly integrate simultaneous audioplaying. AVAudioPlayer wasn't close to precise enough - I'm writing a metronome app.